# Stacking in Weka

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, weka, supervised-learning

I was using metaclassifier 'stacking' to combine two algorithms in Weka, shown in the picture below.

I wonder whether I can use the same algorithms in the classifiers (first cell) and the metaclassifier (third cell). What should be an ideal metaclassifer for my stacking method, if the two algorithms I want to combine are J48 and Multiple Perceptron?

[image: Stacking in Weka]

Answer (score 0):

You already have your two base classifiers that you'll be using with your stacking.  Conceptually speaking, you don't want similar algorithms with similar strengths and weaknesses; learners that are good at different things tend to work better in concert.  You have a decision tree and an MLP, so you're fine in that regard.

Your meta-classifier is going to be any learner of your choice that receives the predictions from your base classifiers.  Those are used as inputs to the meta-classifier.  A key design choice you face with Stacking is ensuring enough diversity in your base classifiers; there are many equally valid choices for your meta-classifier, on the other hand, potentially including whichever learners you used for your base classifications (yes, that's allowed).  So if you want to use an MLP for your meta-learner, that's fine.  If you want something different, that's also fine.  You've already cleared the main hurdle as far as algorithm selection goes.